# How do I use the Expansion Bay on the Asus Essentio CM6850

Tags: installation, case, expansion

There is a panel on the front cover for an Expansion Bay, however it is very shallow and I don't see any evidence of wiring installed.
What can it be used for?

Answer (score 1):

I have checked the [official support site](http://www.asus.com/Desktops/Essentio_CM6850/HelpDesk/) and neither the site nor official documentation mention any sort of expansion bay.

Are you referring to the concave indentation at the top of the PC case, above the USB slots and the card reader?

If so, that is only there for aesthetic reasons, it was their design choice for the case.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxMgT.jpg[image: CM6850]

http://www.asus.com/Desktops/Essentio_CM6850/HelpDesk/

Comment: No. The person has a computer that has an optical drive at the front, and just below that basically a hole into the computer, with the label "expansion bay". it's clearly for some kind of removable drive. the OP (and me) can't figure out what kind of drive goes in there.

Answer (score 1):

I think below picture will be the answer to your question

[image]

source : [Asus CM6850 user manual](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/Desktop/CM6850/E8062_CM6850.pdf)